# Get paginated many to many records in laravel

Tags: laravel

for my app I made it so an user can favorite venues, this relationship between venues and user is many to many, problem is I don't know how to get favorite_venues paginated.

Right now what I'm doing is getting user with favorite_venues but that doesn't seem right to me, is there a way to get favorite venues paginated directly without having to get the user.

What I'm currently doing:

```
public function getFavorites($request)
    {
        $user = User::with(['favoritevenues','favoritevenues.category'])->findOrFail(1);

        return $user;;
    }
```

I set relationships like this:

User Model

```
public function favoritevenues()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Venue', 'favorite_venues', 'user_id', 'venue_id')->withTimeStamps();
    }
```

Venue Model

```
public function favorites()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User', 'favorites', 'venue_id', 'user_id')->withTimeStamps();
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is with the current code? How are you using the data you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

you can do:

```
Venue::whereHas('favorites', function ($q) {
    return $q->where('id', 1);
})->paginate(5);
```

This will get and paginate all the venues which are the favourites of user with id 1